# How can the C compile/linker check if a NOINIT section has initialized data in the source?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, linker, embedded

Using C to build embedded software I have added an additional linker section with the NOLOAD attribute. (NOLOAD creates a section in memory, but not in the binary image file. Similar to the .bss section.)

```
  .buffers (NOLOAD) : 
  {
    *(.buffers)
  } >RAM_D1
```

In the code I create variables for that section using linker attributes:

```
__attribute__((section(".buffers"), used)) uint8_t myBuffer[42];
```

I'd like to get a compiler warning or error if I (or a future programmer) does this:

```
__attribute__((section(".buffers"), used)) uint8_t badFlag = 0x22; // I want this to fail!
```

The compiler and linker don't seem to care and just discards the initialization value. I'd prefer an error or at least a warning. It seems like it would have to be the linker throwing an error or warning because the compiler doesn't know the details of the linker sections.

Is this possible?

Comment: You should at least tag `c` if you want an audience. Your current tags won't get much traction. But I suspect the answer is "no". I doubt the linker can do that.